# Rudin Real and Complex Analysis Proposition 9.8

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

[image]
[image]

Here $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure divided by $\sqrt{2\pi}$.
The first line in the proof is just the definitions. The second line is just the Fubini's theorem. The third line is the change of variables. But if I am not mistaken, we are substituting $u=x-y$ (this gives $y=x-u$) and then writing $y$ in place of $u$. The result of Rudin hence seem to miss a negative sign as $du=-dy$).

Am I correct? If not, what am I missing? If this proposition is not correct, then the result of the rest of the chapter is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\int_0^1 (1-x)  \,dx=1/2=\int_0^1 u \,du$ with no minus signs.
When we change variables, the limits of integration also change, so reverting them to the usual order cancels the minus sign.

Comment: My god I must have been too tired.